# Select all checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have been using bootstrap tables to fetch data from database using kendo datasource. So in order to make it more interactive i have used a checkbox for simultaneous actions.

I want to delete all the entries with one checkbox. I have read about deleting entries with single checkbox using jQuery. But problem is that I have only one checkbox in table and all the entries are being fetched using kendo data source.

If i am creating confusion then see here-

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
  <tr>
      <td> 
          <input type="checkbox" class="done" data-id="#= CID #" ></input>

      </td></tr>
</script>

<table>
<tr>
 <th style="width:10%;">
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now with using kendo datasource i have one column of checkboxes only.

So i am doing this-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.done').click(function (event) {
            if (this.checked) {
                // Iterate each checkbox
                $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                    this.checked = true;
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

And still no result. Help!

Comment: Your html code seems buggy! there is an extra single code and html code in script tag also.

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function(){});` or `$(function(){});` to let it see the whole DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.done').click(function (event) {
        if (this.checked) {
            // Iterate each checkbox
            $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Also, your HTML are wrapped inside the `script` tag, move it outside and remove redundant `'` as well as the `input` tag doesn't need a closing `</input>` tag:

```
<tr>
    <td> 
        <input type="checkbox" class="done" data-id="#= CID #" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){   
     $('.done').click(function (event) {
        if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
            $('input:checkbox:not(".done")').each(function () {
                $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
            });
          }
      });
});
</script>
```

Try this. it may works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {    
    $('.done').on('click', function(){
              // i comment this condition if you want selectall for checked or unchecked
              //if ($(this).is(':checked')){
                        $(':checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
              //}
    });
});
```

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, but this didn't work for me, since i have only single box and with datasource it creates a list of checkboxes.

Comment: @Manoz i think you need to execute this jQuery function after your kendo script.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
   $('.done').click(function (event) {
      $('.chkbxq').each(function () {
        $(this).attr('checked', flag);
      });
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th style="width:10%;">
       <input type="checkbox" class="chkbxq" />
    </th>
  </tr>
</table>
```